# Calculating a de-orbit burn, is this problem written correctly?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, deorbit

I'm having trouble finding the velocity and acceleration for deorbiting burn and therefore the time in seconds it takes, and I find the way the problem is written confusing, especially

> 2. Determination of $\Delta V$:

- Find the change in altitude **(Original Perigee - New Perigee)**
- Use the conversion factor of
  $\left( 0.379\frac{m}{s^2} \over 1km \right)$
- Equation should read:
  $\Delta V = (Change\ in\ Altitude) \times 0.379$

where the units do not even appear to agree, giving delta-v in m/s². Is it just me, or is there something amiss in the question?

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUirG.png) of the original question, below has been kindly transcribed in edits.

---

**The question:**

> During a de-orbit burn, a pre-calculated **∆V (delta V, change in velocity)** will be used to decrease the Orion MPCV’s altitude. The Orion MPCV’s Orbital Maneuvering System (OMS) engines provide a combined **thrust force** of 53,000 Newtons. The Orion MPCV has a **mass** of 25,848 kg when fully loaded.

> What is the difference between the Orion MPCV’s mass and weight? An object’s mass does not change from place to place, but an object’s weight does change as it moves to a place with a different gravitational potential. For example, an object on the moon has the same mass it had while on the Earth but the object will weigh less on the moon due to the moon’s decreased gravitational potential. The Orion MPCV always has the same mass but will weigh less while in orbit than it does while on Earth’s surface.

> **CALCULATION: Calculate how long a de-orbit burn must last in seconds to achieve the Orion MPCV’s change in altitude from 343.5 kilometers to 96.5 kilometers at perigee. Use the equations and conversions provided to find the required burn time.**

> **Equations to use:**

> 1. Newton’s Second Law: $F=ma$

- Where:
- $a$ = acceleration is in meters per second per second $\left( m \over s^2 \right)$ units
- $F$ = force is in Newtons $1N = 1\left(kg−m \over s^2 \right)$
- $M$ = mass is in kg units
- Solve for $a = \frac{F}{m}$

> 2. Determination of $\Delta V$:

- Find the change in altitude **(Original Perigee - New Perigee)**
- Use the conversion factor of
  $\left( 0.379\frac{m}{s^2} \over 1km \right)$
- Equation should read:
  $\Delta V = (Change\ in\ Altitude) \times 0.379$

> 3. Equation that defines average **acceleration**, the amount by which velocity will change in a given amount of time:
>    $a = \frac{\Delta V}{t}$

> 4. Rearranging the acceleration equation above to find the **time required** for a specific velocity change given a specific acceleration, where
>    $t = \frac{\Delta V}{a}$

- $\Delta V$ = change in velocity in meters per second $m \over s$
- $a$ = acceleration is in meters per second per second, $m \over s^2$
- $t$ = required time in **seconds (this is the value that you are solving for)**

(The mix of $M$ and $m$ for both meters and mass is in the [original text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUirG.png))

Comment: @Jack im not sure what the t is because it says to rearrange it to t delta-v/a  I need to find t which should be the answer and I need to put it in seconds

Comment: @Jack Will you be busy for a while? I need help on this very very badly Im having trouble finding the acceleration and im not sure if my velocity is correct

Comment: Fear not! There are plenty of very capable people on here, but I'd advise tidying up the question and making it somewhat clearer to *help them help you*

Comment: Please edit this wall of text down to one single question. You can omit all the background and editorial material.

Comment: What are the values you have obtained for each step so far?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Alrighty the END number I reached is 23 (22.5) but what I did was I divided the mass and the force multipled it by 2 and got 4 I minused the two altitudes and found the altitude difference which was 273.4 I then multiplied it by 0.379 and got 90 (89.9) and I then divided 90 by 4 23 (22.5)

Comment: But im pretty sure this is incorrect^

Comment: What is your value for a in step 1?

Comment: @OrganicMarble the value I got is 4

Comment: How did you get that value, using the equation and values given in the question?

Comment: @OrganicMarble What I did was do the a=f/m near the end of the first one for the 1N= 1(KG-m/s2) i'm not sure what to do with that part I thought what you were supposed to do was use the (s2) to multiply by 2 after dividing the force by the mass I understand this is picking random things out of the equation and going out of order but I've tried many things with none of them working today is my first day getting exposed to physics so please understand my perspective

Comment: @Hrodjdjd Was the big block of text all given to you as a question from an instructor, or does it contain your own work? Where does the factor 0.379 m/s²/km come from? You can't multiply it by the change in height to get delta-v.

Comment: @uhoh yup it was ALL I was given I am so freaking clueless this is my first day being introduced to physics I cant get it at all! all these people downvoting.. im giving them exactly what I received! its an online course

Comment: @uhoh I transcribed the MathJax.  I've proofread it a bunch of times but there may still be errors.  For reference, I've linked the screenshot the OP provided at the bottom of the question.  WRT your last question, that equation is transcribed correctly.

Comment: Then I find the original problem *that you have been given* is very confusing and poorly written, and the interesting part of the problem is hidden inside that 0.379 m/s²/km. I've edited your question to update what I think the *real problem* is; which is the problem you've been given itself! There may not be a problem with your learning physics as much as someone else's problem *teaching it!*

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's supposed to be m/s instead of m/s² -- it's very close to a 2 fps = 1 mile rule-of-thumb for LEO altitude changes, which works out to 0.366 m/s per kilometer.

Comment: im very confused with this still I have no idea how to work with ms and fps ughh im so clueless this is due at 11:59 pm and I absolutely cannot get a zero on this

Comment: I haven't read this too closely but per the suggestion that @RussellBorogove made you might want to see if things make more sense using "0.379 m/s/km" instead of "0.379 m/s²/km".

Comment: @AlexHajnal That was the first thing I did before multiplying by 2 and basically it was also wrong I'm messaging my teacher for help but he is being very vague ish

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87703/discussion-on-question-by-hro-djdjd-calculating-a-de-orbit-burn-is-this-problem).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assume that the 0.379 m/s² / km is a unit error, and the factor is supposed to be 0.379 m/s / km. **I believe this is the fundamental mistake in the problem statement.**

Step 1: The delta-v required is equal to the change in altitude in km, multiplied by the conversion factor. ∆v is measured in meters per second.

Step 2: Compute the acceleration of the spacecraft in m/s² by dividing the given thrust in N by the given mass in kg.

Step 3: Divide the ∆v by the acceleration to get time in seconds.

---

The 0.379 m/s per km is a metricization of a rule of thumb in round Imperial-unit numbers: it's equal to 2 feet-per-second per mile, which isn't even particularly close to the correct value, which varies depending on the starting altitude but is generally closer to 0.3 for LEO maneuvers.

Comment: I was trying to lead the questioner to see their mistake in (your) step 2. I think your problem statement is correct.

Comment: I did this and ended up getting 46.4  but it said it was incorrect

Comment: Change in altitude multiplied by 0.379 = 98.2 the f/m is 2 I then divided these two by doing 98.2/2 and got 46.4 if you're wondering

Comment: Why are you dividing by 2?

Comment: That is the sum given when dividing force by mass it's the acceleration @RussellBorogove

Comment: It's not exactly 2.

Comment: Also my teacher said "first you need to calculate the a
a=F/M 53000/25848
then you calculate the t based on the gravity 
t=92.8/a
then calculate the time in seconds."

Comment: @RussellBorogove it's like 2.05

Comment: So the answer is?

Comment: oh crap when I add 2.05 it becomes an ENTIRELY different number..

Comment: 49.9.. basically 50

Comment: I GOT IT CORRECT THANK YOU GUYS! I WAS ON MY FINAL TRY AND I GOT IT WOOHOOOO!!!

Comment: @Hrodjdjd a [new question was posted](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48388/12102) which I've just edited for clarity and in order to add link back to this page.