# Further understanding of a de-orbit burn problem worked on in 2018

Tags: orbit, burn

I'm having trouble understanding exactly how calculations in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/33180/12102) to *Calculating a de-orbit burn, is this problem written correctly?* were performed.

It’s been a while, but now I’m working on the same problem and can’t figure it out.

Would it be possible to have this explained in a more step-by-step fashion? Thank you

Comment: I've edited the question and I think it's clear enough now.

Comment: Hi, welcome to space, but this is really just a duplicate i.e. restatement of the other question.  Best to handle this over there.  (or maybe in chat would be best)

Comment: @OrganicMarble I agree that one way to do this normally would be to handle there  or in chat, *but users with less than 50 reputation points can not leave comments on other people's posts.* Also, the automatic "Does this answer your question" that SE generates is perhaps less than fortunate in this case because (at)Maria's question already states that it does not. Those auto-generated messages posted with our usernames are editable for five minutes just like any other comment.

Comment: I left an additional comment, boss. Don't fire me!

Comment: @OrganicMarble I don't know how the system started whereby computer generated questions are written and then singed by us got started, but I *try to* always delete and/or edit them.

Comment: I think this question can be salvaged by focusing on one specific problematic part of one specific answer left on the duplicate.